# "cannot import name SparkSession"

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

[I cannot import SparkSession from pyspark.sql,but i can import Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQJWx.png)

my spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6 was install in a docker container,the system is centos

How can I solve the problem?This problem has troubled me for a long time

Answer (score 15):

You cannot use it , because its not present there , the Spark Version that you are using is 1.6 and SparkSession was introduced in 2.0.0.

You can see here: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html

You can download Spark 2.0.0 from here : http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html